# where is the error in the following code in solaris bash?

Tags: bash, solaris

I have wrote in my script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
date=`dat '+%y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
Output=/Tamara/output_$date
echo $Output
`mkdir $Output`
```

But then when I run the script, i get the following:

```
/Tamara/output_23223_242222
mkdir: Failed to make directory "/Tamara/output_23223_342222'; No such file or directory
```

Why is this error displayed ?

Comment: does the Tamara directory exist? and is the script being run by a user that has permissions to create the directory

Comment: Is `Tamara` really located at the root of the file system? Why the backticks on the last line?

Comment: Not a cause of the failure, but why do you have back-ticks around `mkdir $Output` in your script?

Answer (score 2):

**line 1:**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

for a better portability, should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

**line 2:**

```
date=`dat '+%y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
```

A typo here, should be:

```
date=`date '+%y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
```

or better:

```
date=$(date '+%y%m%d_%H%M%S')
```

or even better, to avoid the Y2.1K bug:

```
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
```

**lines 3:**

```
Output=/Tamara/output_$date
```

`/Tamara` is dubious, `~/Tamara` would be better (or perhaps `~Tamara`).

**line 4:**

```
echo $Output
```

No problem with the code of this line but if it really displays `/Tamara/output_23223_242222`, that is both a bogus date and time. I would expect something like `/Tamara/output_130817_215135`

**line 5:**

```
`mkdir $Output`
```

Two issues here, backticks serve no purpose and an option is missing:

```
mkdir -p $Output
```

Comment: And maybe suggest `$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')` in place of the version in back-ticks.  Two changes: (1) How quickly we are forgetting the lessons of Y2K and (2) using `$(...)` is generally easier to understand (especially if there are nested uses of the notation).  It could also be `~Tamara` — it is not clear from the question.